# SQL server jobs precedence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I have a situation where I have a job that runs every day (Job A), job that runs every 2 days (Job B) and another job that runs every weekend (Job C). I need to make sure that Job A runs before Job B. If Job A does not run appropriately then i don't want Job B to run. The same thing applies to Job C. Anyone have any thoughts on how to go about this?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to make sure that Job A runs before Job B. If Job A does not run appropriately then i don't want Job B to run. The same thing applies to Job C.

Create all jobs A,B,C and schedule only job A..At the end of job A ,success event ,Call job B like below

> EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'Weekly Sales Data Backup' ;
>   GO

Now the same things applies to job c,call job c on success event of job B..

I would go with this approach..You also can go with an approach of insert success ,failure values into a table and ensure job b or c reads those values before starting

Answer (score 1):

I have used a product called SQL Sentry to do what you are trying to do. SQL Sentry has a lot of other advanced monitoring and control functionality (like killing jobs that hang, queuing low priority jobs, etc). Here is their website https://sentryone.com/platform/sql-server-performance-monitoring.

This is a quote from one of their [advertising](https://www.sentryone.com/documents/evaluation-highlights.pdf):

> **19. Chaining and Queuing**
>
> Did you ever wish you could find just a few more hours in your
> maintenance window, or need to have jobs run in a particular sequence?
> The advanced chaining features in SQL Sentry Event Manager can assure
> that interdependent jobs run in the proper order without wasting time
> or resources.
>
> **Chaining**
>
> SQL Sentry Event Manager allows you to chain
> SQL Agent Jobs, Windows Tasks, or Oracle Jobs across servers. You can
> enforce dependencies and automate workflow throughout your entire
> enterprise, even across platforms! The graphical chaining interface
> allows you to design the workflow using variables such as completion,
> success, or failure. More details are available in the [User Guide](https://www.sentryone.com/help/ug/webframe.html?Overview.html&Overview.html#Event_Chains.html), but
> take a few minutes to watch our [two video tutorials on chaining](http://sqlsentry.tv/tag/chaining/) -
> Graphical Chaining Interface and Advanced Chaining.